# ことに... at the end of a sentence

Tags: anime

I've seen in an anime (tsurezure children, episode 1, minute 2:00) a boy who was saying this in his mind: "でも、それじゃ こいつ の 告白 を 横取りする ことに…", and I would like to know what that "ことに…" with that ellipsis means. Also, what omitted words would be following that "ことに…" ?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> 「でも、それじゃ こいつ の 告白{こくはく} を 横取{よこどり}りする ことに・・・」

The part left unsaid at the end would be a form of the verb 「なる」, such as 「なってしまう」、「なっちゃう」、「なるだろう」, etc.

> 「Verb Phrase + ことになる」

means:

> "to result in (verb)ing", "to be the same thing as (verb)ing", etc.

For the complete lack of context, however, I have no way of knowing what 「告白を横取りする」 would mean even though I am a native Japanese speaker.  It is simply not a household expression for me.